# Hardware selection for VoIP

Tags: audio, adc, esp8266

I've been trying to make ESP8266 wifi bridge between my landline phone and my mobile to map landline phone on my mobile (VoIP project). I've look for sufficient hardware for ADC at most 8bit bit stream and then use UDP to deliver audio package to mobile. Also I've considered DTMF IC to dial or respond pulse tone.

My problem is I don't have analog  design skill to find min and max specification needed for this project. I don't know  how to select   analog circuits or Audio  codec IC's among plenty of possible options  for this matter. Any advise is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think an ESP8266 has the necessary computational power to pull this off.

Also, for VOIP you really want a fully fledged networking stack, you'll need some kind of multitasking OS and so on, so the ESP8266 is even architecturally not a good fit.

So: do what everyone does, get a Linux-capable box (a raspberry pi or so?), and run linux and a VoIP gateway software on it (for example, asterisk, although that is a really large project). If you search the internet for help on how to "connect {name of VoIP gateway software} to POTS" (POTS = Plain old telephone service), you'll find hardware recommendations. Be warned that handling telephone line signal levels is not very nice for standard components!

Anyway, there's literally hundreds of consumer telephone-VoIP gateways – they often come in the shape of DSL routers. In Germany, for example, the Fritz!Box brand is really popular, and you can buy a used one that talks DSL and plain old telephone on one side, and WiFi, ethernet and VoIP on the other. If you don't have DSL, well, then DSL doesn't work. These things are often sold for much less than 10€, so if you're after a cost-efficient, known-to-work, reliable and easy-to-use solution, go for that.

There's also dedicated cheap POTS-VoIP boxes, but I've never used one of these.

To answer your question regarding requirements:

- Voltage tolerance up to ca +- 50V (Ring voltages are pretty mean!)
- electrical interface to a low-impedance network, with  the option to short-circuit and open the lines (to simulate the physical hang-up)
- some very mediocre current sensitivity for the receiving end
- officially, an adjustable resistance as the "microphone replacement". Think Op-amp controlled current source.
- DTMF tones are the least of your problems – they're just tones. If you have a computer of any kind that produces the audio of your telephone call, it could just as well generate the call tones.

Thinking about that, a good old dial-up modem would do the trick of dialing and physically handling the line for you, and once the connection is made, you could "splice in" your signal path (very much like people used to have modems and telephones on the same physical telephone line, and if you picked up the earpiece while you were online, there was a chance to "hear" the digital transmission until it broke down. Which wasn't pleasant at all.).

Again, very much homebuilt stuff for electronics that are very cheap used and still cheap new, and ship to everywhere in this world that has a postal service (China really isn't that strict on embargoes, but that's a story for another day).

Comment: Thank you very much @Marcus for explanation , actually I've already done audio streaming with ESP8266 even with its ADC pin , similar to this project
https://www.hackster.io/middleca/sending-sound-over-the-internet-f097b4
although quality is not like CD but for simple phone call would be enough
however as I'm not electrical engineering to design analog circuit but I found couple of circuit and IC's for this purpose
My Idea is to make low price gizmo so it can series with landline phone and use landline power to run the device whereas has splitter so phone can operate normally

Comment: As most phone circuits, designed for other purpose and mostly has audio output(speaker , mic) or DAC IC, it is really hard for me to remove unnecessary circuit part 

http://www.next.gr/search.php?what=Telephone+

Comment: well, you can do that with *anything* that attaches to a phone line. Again, just producing audio or recording it is a different thing than handling VoIP. You need to handle compression, complex protocols, buffering, dial logic…

Comment: Seriously, feel invited to look at any library that implements the protocol side of VoIP. When you feel like "hey, that's so easy I could totally implement that on a bare Cortex-M without proper OS", then you only need to port enough Audio codec to make things work. You're way, way, way underestimating the complexity of making complex protocols work.

Comment: it may VOIP title not fit clearly to my project , because I've just intend to use Audio codec  IC such as PCM180x, WM8731, VS1053 to fill UDP buffer and send it over my private network  in period of 60 ms , and controling DFMT IC and other indicator by TCP package ,

Comment: I'm not really intended to mess with VOIP  standard protocol

Comment: then I don't understand your question at all. You definitely say "VoIP" in there, and I don't see how VoIP comes easy, in any way.